# Can connect to VNC server from one location but not another

Tags: vnc

- I have a VNC server running on a desktop at Physical Location (PL) A. (it's behind a router, forwarding port 5900 to the desktop). There is no firewall on the desktop.
- For years I have been able to connect to the VNC server at PL A from PL B, and also able to connect to the VNC server at PL A from PL C
- Recently, I have all of a sudden been UNABLE to connect to the VNC server at PL A from PL B, but still able to connect to the VNC server at PL A from PL C. I can ping the router at PL A from PL B fine.
- From PL B I can first connect to a VPN and then connect to the VNC server at PL A, so I assume there is nothing wrong with the setup at PL B

Any ideas of what could be going wrong here? I'm not sure what else to try to get a more intermediate answer besides "ping works, but connecting to the server does not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the IP of PL B was on a blacklist of the account of the ISP at PL A. I got it removed and all is well.